# Powershell filtering or selecting certain objects

Tags: windows, powershell

So when I run this command:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "*svc*"' | select Name, DistinguishedName
```

I get the following results:

```
SamAccountName       DistinguishedName
--------------       -----------------
svc_myaccount        CN=svc_myaccount,OU=Service Accounts,OU=me3,OU=me2,DC=me,DC=com
```

I would like to filter the DistinguishedName to only provide the first OU only.  I should add that I wouldnt expect "Service Accounts" to be the only item in the OU field. I would like results to be:

```
SamAccountName       DistinguishedName
--------------       -----------------
svc_myaccount        OU=Service Accounts
```

I've been trying to make this a oneliner with using Filter but no luck.  Maybe I have to break up the command and flesh it out to more code to break up DistinguishedName.  I feel like there is a simple solution to this and Im making it more complicated.  Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a nice answer [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/825700-get-aduser-distinguishedname-powershell-help). Pipe `Get-ADUser` to this `Select-Object` statement:

```
select Name,@{l='DistinguishedName';e={$_.DistinguishedName.split(',')[1].split('=')[1]}}
```

The output is:

```
Name              DistinguishedName
----              -----------------
svc_myaccount     Service Accounts
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter does not parse strings, it only returns that data you asked for.
If you are pulling DN, or group strings, or arrays, anything that is not a single string, then you need to parse it yourself, either using substring or regex

Here is one option using regex and split

```
# Parse the DN for the OU array list
Remove the CN and split
('CN=svc_myaccount,OU=Service Accounts,OU=me3,OU=me2,DC=me,DC=com' -replace 'CN=[^=]*,') -split(',')

# Results

OU=Service Accounts
OU=me3
OU=me2
DC=me
DC=com

#Get just the first element of the above array - arrays are zero based
(('CN=svc_myaccount,OU=Service Accounts,OU=me3,OU=me2,DC=me,DC=com' -replace 'CN=[^=]*,') -split(','))[0]

#Results

OU=Service Accounts
```

Using the above approach with a calculated property

```
# Pulling live from ADDS
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "*svc*"' | 
Select-Object -Property Name, 
@{Name='DistinguishedName';Expression = { (($_.DistinguishedName -replace 'CN=[^=]*,') -split(','))[0]}}
```

Or this as the calculated property...

```
 ('CN=svc_myaccount,OU=Service Accounts,OU=me3,OU=me2,DC=me,DC=com').split(',|=')[3]
```

... using an or (the pipe between the two spilt stings) in the split. It's a regex thing as well which works with .split